# React Native, How to convert nested if else into switch statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Hye, I'm new to react-redux I'm struggling to convert a nested if else statement into switch statement. Can anyone tell me how to do that? below is my code

```
if (action.type === ADD_TO_CART) {
    let addedItem = state.jeans.find((item) => item.id === action.id);
    let existed_item = state.addedItems.find((item) => action.id === item.id);
    if (existed_item) {
      addedItem.quantity += 1;
      return {
        ...state.jeans,
        total: state.total + addedItem.price,
      };
    } else {
      addedItem.quantity = 1;
      let newTotal = state.total + addedItem.price;

      return {
        ...state,
        addedItems: [...state.addedItems, addedItem],
        total: newTotal,
      };
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What problem are you having with the code as it is?

Comment: I don't have any problem but my sir said that I need to write this into switch.. can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you just wanted to switch it from **if else** to **switch** right?

In this case you can the following I guess:

```
if (action.type === ADD_TO_CART) {
    let addedItem = state.jeans.find((item) => item.id === action.id);
    let existed_item = state.addedItems.find((item) => action.id === item.id);
    switch(existed_item){
        case !undefined: {
            addedItem.quantity += 1;
            return {
              ...state.jeans,
              total: state.total + addedItem.price,
            };
        }
        default: {
            addedItem.quantity = 1;
            let newTotal = state.total + addedItem.price;
        
            return {
              ...state,
              addedItems: [...state.addedItems, addedItem],
              total: newTotal,
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and for `if (action.type === ADD_TO_CART)` is `Switch(action.type){ case ADD_To_Cart{` so basically for for nested if else we need nested switch statement right?

Comment: yeah exactly, I thought you meant just for inner but if you want all as switch yes your approach is true :)

Comment: Thnx, but I'm old user someone downvoted my 4-5 questions which I already marked as answer so they blocked my account to ask questions

Comment: @KanwarjeetSingh yeah I got you, I had same problem actually :) 1-2 of my accounts got blocked with same reason, cuz I didnt know how to ask questions nicely..

Answer (score 1):

And your sir is right. It should be written with switch as there is a good chance the list of actions types will increase and you'll have multiple cases.

It should be something like this:

s

```
switch(action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
        let addedItem = state.jeans.find((item) => item.id === action.id);
        let existed_item = state.addedItems.find((item) => action.id === item.id);
        if (existed_item) {
          addedItem.quantity += 1;
          return {
            ...state.jeans,
            total: state.total + addedItem.price,
          };
        } else {
          addedItem.quantity = 1;
          let newTotal = state.total + addedItem.price;
    
          return {
            ...state,
            addedItems: [...state.addedItems, addedItem],
            total: newTotal,
          };
        }
   default:
        return state;  // or something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This way ....

```
switch (action.type) {

    case ADD_TO_CART :

        let addedItem = state.jeans.find((item) => item.id === action.id);
        let existed_item = state.addedItems.find((item) => action.id === item.id);
        
        const itemExists = existed_item ? true : false; 
        switch (existed_item) {

           case true : 

              addedItem.quantity += 1;
              return {
                ...state.jeans,
                total: state.total + addedItem.price,
              };          

           case false :

              addedItem.quantity = 1;
              let newTotal = state.total + addedItem.price;
              return {
                ...state,
                addedItems: [...state.addedItems, addedItem],
               total: newTotal,
             };
         }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  switch(existed_item) {
  case true:
   addedItem.quantity += 1;
   return {
    ...state.jeans,
    total: state.total + addedItem.price,
   };

   case false:
    addedItem.quantity = 1;
     let newTotal = state.total + addedItem.price;

    return {
      ...state,
      addedItems: [...state.addedItems, addedItem],
      total: newTotal,
  };
default:
  return null;
}
```